Gunslinger who looks like Lance Henriksen
A movie from the 1990s (maybe late 80s) about a gunslinger who everyone is trying to take out. He returns to town and his ex, thinking he was dead (in the Civil War?) has remarried and has a child. At the end of the movie he finds out that the child (a girl) was his.
I had thought the actor was Lance Henriksen from Aliens but just checked IMDB and I am not finding it.
EDIT: FLASHES OF SCENES:
Near the beginning he's sitting in a bar eating lunch and the owner of the bar starts berating the Mexican server, then pushes him to his knees and demands that he mops the floor with a rag. The gunman interferes, says men shouldn't work on their knees and makes the owner do the work. He then asks the server if he knows a place where he can get a good meal of rice and beans and then leaves with the server.
The town hears / finds out he's the famous gunman and a little kid (5) comes out and goes "stick-em-up", or "draw. Then gunman whirls and is sickened by the fact that he's on edge at all times.
His ex says that when he left he wanted to be known as the best gunman in the west; now that he is - is he happy about it? No.
At the end the husband is forced (forget why) to a gunfight in which he is woefully outmatched and the gunman takes his place. Kills the opponents (some were professional gunmen) and leaves town. The girl finds out that he's her father and rides after him. And then ... she goes back(?)

Do you remember where you saw it? Any other particular scenes?

@Walt - added some scenes.

Well, one film starring Lance Henriksen does fit the description - The 1997 Western Gunfighter's Moon:

[Henriksen] plays Frank Morgan, a notorious and feared gunfighter that has lived his life on the run. His face and eyes reveal a man that has been very much hardened by that life. We quickly learn, however, that there is still passion inside. Upon receiving a telegram from Linda, an old lover (played by Kay Lenz), requesting his presence, he abandons his woman, mounts his horse and rides to Linda without giving it a second thought. Upon arrival, he learns that Linda is now happily married to the owner of the local general store. The only vestige of her past that remains is a daughter, who Frank is surprised to learn is his. 

The rest is in there too. Here's the trailer:




Interesting I found it. (See comment below). I didn't refresh the page (was left open in a tab) and didn't even see your post. Thank you.

ANSWERING MY OWN QUESTION:
I became obsessed in finding the answer. 
I went to findanyfilm.com and entered the parameters 
GENRE: Western
RELEASE YEAR: 1990 - 1999
and, after scrolling through the movies, found http://www.findanyfilm.com/Gunfighters-Moon~4296
That's the movie!!! And Lance Henriksen IS in it. Went back to IMDB and there it is, plain as day. Don't know how I missed it the first time around.
Well. Case closed. The movie is Gunfighter's Moon. If you like cowboy movies - this is worth a watch.

Nicely done, though you can also simply cross-reference Western & Lance Henriksen on IMDb. ;)
